# MAMP fails to upgrade mysql databases

Tags: php, mysql, mamp, mysqlupgrade

When I run MAMP, it asks me to upgrade mysql databases and once I click okay, I get

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Looking for 'mysql' as: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqlcheck
Error: Failed while fetching Server version! Could be due to unauthorized access.
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

error. I tried a lot of searching, but can't find any solution that would work for me. It's annoying because of this I can't load my localhost project or even connect to phpmyadmin to make a backup of my databases. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that MAMP does not get access because of wrong username or password in MySQL. I have faced one similar issue earlier & got fixed.

The answer should be to set both `username & password to the default value = root`.

Log on to mysql database with terminal(mac).

```
* /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -h localhost -uroot
* USE mysql;
* SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('root');
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Wouldn‘t it be practical just to install an updated version of MySQL, still compatible with MAMP, like 5.8 or 6.0 and re-config the `config.inc.php` file? because MAMP does not support the last version.